# Detecting if a Callable is Static

Tags: d

I thought I would be able to do this with std.traits.functionAttributes, but it does not support `static`. For any type of callable (structs with opCall included), how can I tell if that callable is annotated with `static`? For example:

```
template isStaticCallable(alias fun) if (isCallable!fun)
{
    enum isStaticCallable = ...?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Traits](http://dlang.org/traits.html%20Traits) are part of dlang which provide insight into compile time information. One of the available traits is `isStaticFunction` used as `__traits(isStaticFunction, fun)`.

Example code:

```
import std.traits;

template isStaticCallable(alias fun) if (isCallable!fun)
{
    enum isStaticCallable = __traits(isStaticFunction, fun);
}


void main() {}

class Foo
{
    static void boo() {}
    void zoo() {}
}

pragma(msg, isStaticCallable!main); // note that this prints true because
                                    // the function has no context pointer
pragma(msg, isStaticCallable!(Foo.boo)); // prints true
pragma(msg, isStaticCallable!(Foo.zoo)); // prints false
```